# Testing method with many exception on

Tags: java, testng

Hello i have 30 exception that are thrown by 30 values I pass to my test on the same method which takes the input,but it seems I cannot put the exception in the catch block,is there any workaround?

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] providedInfo()
{
    return new Object[][] 
            {    
            {MyGuests1.class,SQLException.class} //and many more
            };
}

@Test(dataProvider="providedInfo")
public void f(Class c , Throwable ex)  {

  ItemsRepository x =new ItemsRepository();
 try{
  x.findAll(c);
 }
 catch(Throwable ex)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Please add a language tag and correctly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html rule.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();


@DataProvider
public Object[][] providedInfo()
{
    return new Object[][] 
            {    
            {MyGuests1.class,SQLException.class} //and many more
            };
}

@Test(dataProvider="providedInfo")
public void f(Class c , Throwable ex)  {
  thrown.expect(ex);
  ItemsRepository x =new ItemsRepository();
  x.findAll(c);
}
```

If there throw is as expected the test case will fail. There is also some more verbose testing options with it.

Additionally you may want to look into assertJ if you are using Java 8 or greater as it has some additional measures for excption testing which may help, but I generally find their API better.